# Salesforce not-for-profit license upgrade

Tags: licenses, enterprise

We have a client that currently has a license for Salesforce professional edition. They are a not-for-profit, so they qualify for 10 free enterprise edition licenses under the NFP discount program, so they'd like to upgrade to enterprise edition.

They were told by their Salesforce sales rep that they'll need to migrate to a new org to upgrade, is this really the case? I didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: Ask if they will perform the migration for you, if that is indeed the requirement.

Comment: The account manager won't be the best resource to find out information about non-profit organization information. You need to contact the [Salesforce Foundation](http://www.salesforcefoundation.org/) and ask them directly. While it's not ordinarily true that you'd need to create a new org while upgrading (e.g. Professional Edition to Enterprise Edition), there are limitations in place that prevent certain types of upgrades, such as Developer Edition to Professional Edition (as an arbitrary example). Should you find out, I'd suggest you answer here for future visitors.